# VBA amend code to add text in a column if a specific text value

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,

The below code only adds the worksheet name to column cell range D2-D5 regardless of what text is in cells D2-D5.

Can I get your guidance to amend the code that if there is a specific word "Category" or "Store" in column D that it adds the worksheet Name and "_" into the cell value which is either going to be "Category" "Store" instead of it only being applicable to cells D2-D5 per the below code?

e.g:

Sheet1_Category
Sheet1_Store

```
 ws.Range("D2").Value = ws.Name & "_" & ws.Range("D2").Value
                ws.Range("D3").Value = ws.Name & "_" & ws.Range("D3").Value
                ws.Range("D4").Value = ws.Name & "_" & ws.Range("D4").Value
                ws.Range("D5").Value = ws.Name & "_" & ws.Range("D5").Value
                DoEvents
                ws.Copy
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sheetDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & ws.Name & "_" & wbName
                DoEvents
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                validWs = True
        End If
    Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be using an `IF` and `INSTR` like so

```
If instr(1,ws.Range("D3").Value,"CATEGORY")>0 then 
   ws.Range("D3").Value = ws.Name & "_" & ws.Range("D3").Value
end if
```

Or you could use `like`

```
if ws.Range("D3").Value like "*CATEGORY*" then
```

or you could use `range("D:D").find`

this will help http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

Comment: Can i clarify because i need it to do a search for any cell value that contains the words "Category" OR "Store" in column D i am removing the "D3" and amending it to "D:D"

Answer (score 0):

I have factored in the above to generate the below amended code:

```
  categoryData = ws.Range("D1").Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.count, 1)
                For i = 1 To UBound(categoryData)
                    If categoryData(i, 1) = "store" Then categoryData(i, 1) = ws.Name & "_" & categoryData(i, 1)
                    If categoryData(i, 1) = "category" Then categoryData(i, 1) = ws.Name & "_" & categoryData(i, 1)
                Next i
                ws.Range("D1").Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.count, 1) = categoryData
                DoEvents
                ws.Copy
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sheetDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & ws.Name & "_" & wbName
                DoEvents
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                validWs = True
        End If
    Next ws
```